# Combine serverless Azure functions in code but run independently

Tags: azure, serverless

If you need to create 5 related serverless azure functions that have similar dependencies and a large portion of the code would be the same, do you have to create and maintain 5 separate Visual Studio solutions/projects?  Is it possible to create one solution/project in Visual Studio but then spawn 5 instances (passing in a different parameter to each one)?

For example, 1 is timer based and runs Function1
another is queue based and runs Function2
etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have one function App with multiple types of triggers and share the logic between them.

There's even support for Dependency Injection:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Comment: I only have limited experience with dependency injection, not sure how you would use it to achieve the objective of having different triggers

Comment: No, there's no relationship with the triggers...my point was that you could extract the logic and inject a service into your functions.